# Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException Route [download] not defined

Tags: laravel, routes

##### `index.blade.php`

```html
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('download', $country->file) }}">Download</a></li>
```

##### Route

```php
Route::post('download{file}', [DocumentController::class, 'download']);
```

Controller

```php
public function download(Request $request, $file)
{
    $data = Country::all();
    
    return response()->download(public_patch('asset/'.$file));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your route should look like this

```php
Route::post('/download/{file}', [DocumentController::class, 'download'])->name('download');
```

Comment: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

i use your recommended route but i got this weird error

Comment: well it says in the error that you have to use the POST method and NOT the GET method!